# Performance issue with emulator program running without sudo

Tags: permissions, performance, emulation

I'm attempting to run an emulator (VisualBoyAdvanced) on a Pine64 single-board computer running Ubuntu 16.04. The program works fine when running as root (with the `sudo` command), but because of my pulseaudio setup I get no sound at all. Running the program without root works, but I get a huge hit to performance (roughly running at 1FPS), making the emulator unusable.

What causes a program running without root access to take a performance hit? There's no errors at all, the emulator even is saving files correctly. Perhaps there is some hardware element in my board that can only be accessed by the root user (this seems strange to me, as I don't believe I've ever seen any kind of **permission limitation directly affecting performance**)?

Please let me know if I can provide additional details.